# Disable google map zooming on mouse hover is not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below is stopping the map zoom in zoom out on mouse hover scroll in all the browsers only IE is not taking it. When i scroll the page down and mouse comes up on map it stops scrolling the page and starts zooming google map on IE

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        // you want to enable the pointer events only on click;

        $('#map_canvas1').addClass('scrolloff'); // set the pointer events to none on doc ready
        $('#canvas1').on('click', function () {
            $('#map_canvas1').removeClass('scrolloff'); // set the pointer events true on click
        });

        // you want to disable pointer events when the mouse leave the canvas area;

        $("#map_canvas1").mouseleave(function () {
            $('#map_canvas1').addClass('scrolloff'); // set the pointer events to none when mouse leaves the map area
        });
    });

<div id="canvas1" class="map">
     <iframe id="map_canvas1" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embe...." width="1170" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border: 0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, explain the desired behavior and how IE behaves

Comment: The code above is stopping the map zoom in zoom out on mouse hover scroll in all the browsers only IE is not taking it. When i scroll the page down and mouse comes up on map it stops scrolling the page and starts zooming google map on IE.

Comment: You should edit the question instead of adding a comment

Comment: Are you expecting the class `.scrolloff` to somehow block the event handlers of mouse events on the map? If you are, please post all the code related to `.scrolloff`